# how to replace multiple value in single regex?

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I have some values like `10++10--10+-10-+`.my question is how to replace these value into matched value using single reg expression.i need a answer like `10+10-10-10-`.
     its means

```
'++'='+',
'--'='-',
'+-'='-',
'-+'='-';
```

.please help me for solve my problem.

Comment: what about `--++`? will there be any such value

Comment: I have no idea where you get these values, but if there's some "math-logic" shouldn't `'--'='+'`?

Comment: No.its just ah constant

Comment: `'10++10--10+-10-+'.replace(/(\+\+)|([-+]-|-\+)/g, function(m,g1,g2){return g1?"+":"-";});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Match and capture the alternatives you need to replace with a specific string, and then use the replace callback to see which group matched and replace accordingly:

```js
var s = '10++10--10+-10-+';
document.body.innerHTML = s.replace(/(\+\+)|([-+]-|-\+)/g, function(m, g1, g2) { 
  return g1? "+" : "-";
});
```

The `(\+\+)|([-+]-|-\+)` regex contains 2 alternative groups since there are 2 replacement patterns. Group 1 `(\+\+)` will match double pluses while Group 2 - `([-+]-|-\+)` - matches and captures `--`, `+-` and `-+`.

Answer (score 1):

A solution that is Regex only without callback function, so that it can be applicable in other languages that do not have regex replacement callbacks.

```js
var s = '10++10--10+-10-+';
document.body.innerHTML = (s + "||||++=>+,+-=>-,-+=>-,--=>-" // Append replacements
  ).replace(/(\+\+|--|-\+|\+-)(?=[\s\S]*\1=>([^,]*))|\|\|\|\|[\s\S]*$/g, "$2" 
// Perform replacements and remove replacements
  )
```